# How to set environment variables in vscode for debugging?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, pythonpath

I have a fairly large python/c++ program that runs as follow:

1. . set_env.sh -option A -option B
2. python run.py

The set_env.sh script modifies the PYTHONPATH and does all sort of export in order to point to the right c++ program.
When running these two commands in the terminal, that works just well, however, using the debugger breaks it all.

I try running ". set_env.sh -option A -option B" in preLaunchTask but it seems the debugger can't see the new PYTHONPATH.

How can I make the debugger run the the set_env and consider the new PYTHONPATH ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspired by my current area of work - which involved Python.

### This is what I do for Flask.

[image]

### MS Link

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

### For any regular Python debugging

[image]

### Evidence

```py
import os

for key in os.environ.keys():
    print(f"{key}={os.environ.get(key)}")
```

After doing a F5 in VS Code with a file containing the above snippet:
[image]

### Update on Feb 18

After receiving a comment I think the OP wants to run a script before debugging the Fask application. The steps that worked for me are below.

### Overview

I ended up with the following files:

- Add a PowerShell file `dosomething.ps1` (my custom script which I intend to launch before every debug session)
- Add a `task.json` (launch dosomething.ps1)
- Edit the existing `launch.json` by linking it with the task in `task.json`
  [image]

### The file dosomething.ps1

```
Write-Host "Inside do something"
Write-Host "The value of the environment variable TEMP is $env:TEMPcls"
Write-Host "The current path of the script is $PSScriptroot"
```

### The file tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "my script task",
            "type": "shell",
            "windows": {
                "command": "pwsh -f dosomething.ps1"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

### Linking the launch.json with task.json

[image]

### After pressing F5

[image]

Comment: This is the same answer as @fitzberg but it does not work since the script `set_env.sh` has to be launched before each debugging session :/

Comment: @Welgriv  Please see my updates to the original answer (section marked with Feb 18). I am launching a PowerShell script before launching the Fask debugger

Comment: I can't verify if this works on Windows but on Mac the script will run but then the debugger command will fail to run and sit waiting to attach.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and could solve it by setting environment variables in the "env" field of the launch.JSON file. This shoudl be stored in a `.vscode` folder in your project root, here is the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

I discovered the "env" field in this snippet here: https://gist.github.com/slaveofcode/b4c18efc99c16029913cde3fd2dba3ce

Not sure how to configure this dynamically with the `-option A -option B` however. Hope this helps :)

Comment: We are close to the solution but it does not work since the script `set_env.sh` has to be launched before each debugging session :/